# MYSQL query involving 'not exists'

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

I have a university practical next week on databases. I need to create 15 queries around a scheme on a university, which looks as follows:

- Student(Student_No, First_Name , Last_Name, Sex, Date-Of-Birth, Address, Level,  Degree_Code)
- Degree(Degree_Code, Degree_Name, School_Name)
- Module(Module_Code, Module_Title, School_Name)
- School(School_Name, Faculty, Head-of-School)
- Take_Exam(Student_No, Module_Code, Mark)

I have completed 14 of the queries but I am stuck on this one:

- Retrieve the names of students who take every Module.  (Hint. use not exists).

I have been reading up on not exists queries, but I just don't even know where to start!
I created this piece of code:

```
select students.student_no, fname, lname, count(module_code)
from students left join take_exam using (student_no)
group by student_no
having count(module_code) < 19
order by lname;
```

This returns all students who DON'T take all 19 modules. However, I hate the code as it involves having < 19, which meant if the amount of modules ever changed later, this value would need changes which is inefficient.

Can anyone point me in the right direction and give me some guidance on using 'not exists' queries?

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Hint: you'll need a second NOT EXISTS. (there is no mudule that he/she has not taken)

Comment: @wildplasser: If I'm honest, that's what I feared! Never used one before, let alone two. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Once you've done it, it all seems trivial. NOT EXISTS is very close to natural language/logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `not exists` :

```
select *
from Student s1 
where not exists 
         (select 1 
          from Module 
          where Module_Code not in
                      (select Module_Code 
                       from Take_Exam 
                       where Student_No = s1.Student_No)
```

Explanation :

For each student `s` in the table `Student`, we'll add `s` to the result, iff :
not exists any module in table `Module` such that this module is not mapped to student `s` in table `Take_Exam`.

It's not intuitive, but it's exactly the same as :
"all the students who take every module"

Comment: Can I ask what the '1' does in your first nested query?

Comment: `not exists` checks if the result of the query is not empty - so it doesn't matter what to select, `1` or `*`..

Comment: Your code works perfectly, but I'm having some difficulties working through the syntax. Would you mind explaining in what order MYSQL works through this query and what each step does? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - I've added some explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without completely answering your homework for you, here's a hint that might help:

Try looking at it from another angle.  Students that answered all module question will not have any null fields with a left join to the module table, correct?

Also,you probably don't need a left outer join to the `table_exam`... since you want only students having taken the exam.

Comment: Thanks from the advice from both of you - I'll try and rejig my coding!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can get `distinct count of modules from module table` and then use that in comparison e.g. below:

```
     select students.student_no, fname, lname, count(t.module_code)
     from module m, students join take_exam t using (student_no)
     group by student_no
     having count(t.module_code) = count(distinct(m.module_code)) 
     order by lname;
```

Please note: I changed the condition to `=` and join to `inner join` as **you wanted students taking all modules.**

EDIT: Using notExit:

```
     select students.student_no, fname, lname 
     from students 
     WHERE  NOT EXISTS (select *
                from module m, students join take_exam t using (student_no)
                group by student_no
                having count(t.module_code) < count(distinct(m.module_code)) 
                group by student_no
             )
     order by lname;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however, I think I HAVE to use a NOT EXISTS query (even if it's not the easiest way to do it). Additionally, your code doesn't like the having count(module_code) - it says this is ambiguous.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: Added a qualifier `t.` in the `count(module_code)` as `count(t.module_code)`. Updated the query. Please check.

Comment: I do want to accept the answer, and I find the logic you use easier, but I think I HAVE to use a not exists query :(

Comment: @AndrewMartin: Added one answer with `not exists`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I'm getting incorrect results from the query.

Comment: It returns all 16 students in the table